# bit endianness and portability of C binary files

Tags: c, file, endianness

In C, I have a char array that I use to store data at the bit level. I store these arrays to files, then read them in machines with different architectures. My question is if the order of the bits will be guaranteed consistent? For example, if I store "10010011" to the first byte, will the adjacent 1's always be read to be in the 2^0 and 2^1 positions, or could they end up interpreted as the 2^7 and 2^6 bits?

EDIT: I want to clarify this question a little for people who read this page later. Byte endianness is the order of bytes in a multibyte object, but my concern is with the bits in a given byte. When a byte is stored to disc, it is stored as a sequence of (usually) 8 bits. I'm no hardware expert, but it has to come down to that somehow. So, my concern is if the way the byte is stored is such that any machine will read the original unsigned char value, or if what is 3 to one machine will be 192 to another. I am concerned the bits will end up shuffled somehow. Apparently, this is not a concern, according to the answer I selected as well as one of the comments below. Thanks.

Comment: I sincerely hope you are aware that C does not even try to guarantee the size of a byte, aside from saying it must be at least 8 bit, as a concession to architectures which don't like 8-bit-bytes all that much...

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I am relying on the guarantee of at least 8 bits, so the higher order bits, if present, shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: If you restrict yourself to architectures with 8-bit-char (everything modern, with few exceptions which use a higher power-of-2), you are fine if you restrict yourselt to reading and writing `unsigned char`s, and manually (de-)serializing everything more complex from them. More guarantees will make things easier and faster though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple answer:

The bits will still be in the correct order.

However, if performing any format conversion beyond %c, for instance %d, then the endianness of the reading architecture will determine the byte order  The bits within each byte will still be the same.

Comment: `%d` means nothing in this situation. If OP uses it to convert a numerical value to a printable representation, endianness is entirely taken out of the picture (although it is replaced with "text representation compatibility", which is a similar issue).

Answer (score 0):

Endianness is about bytes' order not bits. So 00001101 in a little-endian machine will be the same in a big-endian machine. However there is something you should now about bits' order in different machines. Bits' order change in unions. If you are going to use union, read [this](http://mjfrazer.org/mjfrazer/bitfields/) to figure out how endianness effects bitfield packing.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are trying to ask about is known as [bit-numbering or bit endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) and system architectures are referred to as least-or most- significant bit (MSB, LSB) ordering.

As far as I know the reference is always with respects to the 0-th or first bit position.

With respect to a *single* 8-bit byte or octet, it will be portable, such that the value of the byte will be consistently considered to be 0x93 (147 decimal). Assuming you are writing the bit string as a LSB representation with the 0-th bit is the rightmost bit (the norm for little endian processor), as typically done by users of left to right natural languages such as English.